# I'm having an issue with what would seem to be a simple insert using MyBatis/java.

Tags: java, insert, sequence, mybatis

I'm having an issue with what would seem to be a simple insert using myBatis and java.

The exception is:

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: 
    Error preparing statement. Cause: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    Array index out of range: 12
```

The query in my mapper is as follows:

```
<insert id="insertRuleResult"
    useGeneratedKeys="true"
    keyProperty="ruleResult.recordDetailId"
    keyColumn="RECORD_DETAIL_ID">

INSERT INTO KMV_DBO.RULE_RESULT(
    RECORD_ID,
    RECORD_DETAIL_ID,
    SUBJECT_AREA_ID,
    RULE_NAME,
    RULE_RESULT,
    MESSAGE,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    ORIGINAL_VALUE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    STATUS,
    SOURCE,
    USER_NOTE,
    CREATED_DATE,
    BATCH_STATUS,
    UPDATED_BY,
    UPDATED_DATE
)
VALUES (
    KMV_DBO.RULE_IMPACTED_DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    #{ruleResult.subjectAreaId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.ruleName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.ruleResult,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.message,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.columnName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.originalValue,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.newValue,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.recordId,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
    #{ruleResult.status,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.source,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    #{ruleResult.userNote,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    SYSDATE,
    'Open',
    #{user.nwieId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
    NULL
)
</insert>
```

I tried the following variation, but it also doesn't work if I'm not using the schema owner id to connect.  The error was sequence not found:

```
<insert id="insertRuleResult">
  <selectKey keyProperty="ruleResult.recordDetailId" keyColumn="RECORD_DETAIL_ID" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
      SELECT RULE_IMPACTED_DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO KMV_DBO.RULE_RESULT(
      RECORD_ID,
      RECORD_DETAIL_ID,
      SUBJECT_AREA_ID,
      RULE_NAME,
      RULE_RESULT,
      MESSAGE,
      COLUMN_NAME,
      ORIGINAL_VALUE,
      NEW_VALUE,
      STATUS,
      SOURCE,
      USER_NOTE,
      CREATED_DATE,
      BATCH_STATUS,
      UPDATED_BY,
      UPDATED_DATE
  ) VALUES (
      #{ruleResult.recordId,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
      #{ruleResult.recordDetailId,jdbcType=NUMERIC},
      #{ruleResult.subjectAreaId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.ruleName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.ruleResult,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.message,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.columnName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.originalValue,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.newValue,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.status,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.source,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{ruleResult.userNote,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      SYSDATE,
      'Open',
      #{user.nwieId,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      NULL
  )
</insert>
```

The values being inserted are basic strings and numbers.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: The sequence not found error from your second example sounds like a permissions issue.  Consider whether the user associated with that statement has all the necessary grants

Comment: Oh, and you didn't specify the schema for that example (maybe `SELECT KMV_DBO.RULE_IMPACTED_DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL`? My Oracle is rusty)

Comment: Oy vey.....  Yep, I forgot to specify the schema in the 2nd attempt.   That fixes the issue for me.  Thanks for the 2nd set of eyeballs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: 
>       Error preparing statement. Cause: 
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
>       Array index out of range: 12

It means it fails at 13th (because internal array is zero-based) value which is `SYSDATE`.

I would advise, try to insert hard coded values first to see if it works then pass dynamic value.

Comment: I was about to take your advice and change the parameters in the VALUES to hard coded values.   Then I noticed I had somehow messed up the order of the values in the VALUES clause.  Fixing this gets rid of the exception   Wow... They're going to take away my coding card.   Anyway, thanks for the advice!